# How to create a menu in Vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, webpack, web-applications

I want to create a menu on Vue.js 2 It should open a default page "statistics". After pressing buttons change the page. How can I do it?[Default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bifwQ.png)

Actually, I don't understand how to open a default page or how to hide it after pressing on another page.
Maybe I can use v-if, v-else on buttons?